# Is there a way to avoid caching data during run-time?

Tags: c, caching

I'm currently studying the run-time of Cache-Oblivious algorithms for matrix multiplications.

When comparing Cache-Optimized approaches vs Naive approaches(e.i the a simple matrix multiplication algorithm), the performance of the naive approach is significantly improved since all operand matrices are already cached.

Is there any way to turn off data caching while initializing the operand matrices and then turn it on for the remmaining of the program?

Filling-up the cache is not a viable solution for my problem. I need to run around 500 tests for large matrices. I'm not able to have these tests running for a week.

I'm also using working in a shared server. An ideal solution would just turn off caching in user space.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: My OS is Debian and the programming language is C.

Comment: Would you accept [removing the matrix from the cache](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44428520/555045), instead of temporarily disabling caching?

Comment: On Microsoft Windows, you can make memory non-cacheable by calling [VirtualProtect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualprotect) with the `PAGE_NOCACHE` parameter. I'm sure that there is something equivalent for Linux.

Comment: @harold's comment seems like a viable solution. Thanks for the reply!